# Comparing each line in txt file to another text file in each line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i'm having some difficulties about shell script these days.
Done some test and still can't make it work.
I'm trying to compare each line in a text file to another text file. The idea is to see if some line is not in the file2.

Could someone see what is wrong on my script ?

Thanks!!

```
#!/bin/bash
  FILE1='/filePath/file.txt'
  FILE2='/filePath/file2.txt'
  for line in $FILE1 
  do
    for line2 in $FILE2
    do
        if  $line != $line2
            then
            echo -e /> diffsScr.txt
        fi
    done 
  done
```

Comment: Why not using the command `diff`? Also, better show input / desired output.

Comment: because he's not giving me the right output, already tried. He still give me lines that is in the both files. Not what i want :/

Comment: Note `man diff` is full of options. Give a read to it because you may find the one that helps you!

Comment: (only looking at logic) The way your loops are set up you are comparing each line of file1 to all the lines in file2. It sounds like you want to compare line-by-line.

Comment: thats exactly what i want. To know if some line is not the in the second file

Comment: What is the purpose of overwriting `diffsScr.txt` with a single forward slash?  This doesn't seem to provide you any useful output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{f[$0]+=1; next} !($0 in f)' input1 input2
```

This reads through the file `input1` and builds an array.  Then it goes through `input2` and prints each line that did not appear in `input1`.  If you want to add line numbers:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{f[$0]+=1; next} !($0 in f) { print FNR, $0}' input1 input2
```

One big advantage of this approach is that it scales well.  Your approach is O(n*m) where n and m are the number of lines in the files, but pre-reading into a array like this gives you a solution that is O(n+m).  In other words, you only read through each file once.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result with command:

```
fgrep -v -x -f '/filePath/file2.txt' '/filePath/file1.txt'
```

Comment: what does "-v" and "-f" do ?

Answer (score 0):

If your files are sorted, you can use *comm* to compare files.

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

Description of comm:

```
   Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.

   With  no  options,  produce  three-column  output.  Column one contains
   lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to  FILE2,  and
   column three contains lines common to both files.

   -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

   -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

   -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```